# ASP.net Resource Files not being copied to bin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, globalization

I have a multi-lingual MVC web application referencing multiple projects.  The application's resources are also defined in separate projects/modules, for example Application.Models.Resources.

This approach has worked well with the initial language set but now I have added additional languages to the resource projects, the new language resources dlls are not be copied to the application's /bin folder.  For example, a Swedish language ('sv') variant was added to the resource project, it is not being copied to the /bin/sv folder of the application.

The resource file has its Access Modifier set to 'Public'.

What am I missing?  How can I ensure that the language variants are installed?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: how you are publishing your project ?? usually we always face such situation when publishing to local system files. a workaround to fix it is to change from debug to release or inversely in the publishing wizard.

Comment: Hi Sam, the required folder/dll is not even appearing in the source application's /bin folder after a clean and solution rebuild.  I have 'sort of' found a fix by unloading the resource project from the solution and then reloading it again - which is OK, but it means you have to re-link all the references,

Comment: have you tried switching between debug and release ?

Comment: Hi Sam, yes, I tried that but it didn't make any difference.  What I haven't yet tried is unloading and loading the project - I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: I was not able to test unloading/reloading the project as removing and then re-referencing the projects achieved achieved two things: i) it made the main application recognise the new language variants and ii) it fixed the problem for new languages added to the resource project going forward.  I am not sure what was wrong with the original references, but this approach resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst there might be other solutions to this problem, I found that removing the references to the resource projects from the solution and then re-referencing them (Add existing project) fixed the problem.  Other users with this problem might also want to try unloading and then reloading the resource projects (I was unable to test this as the first method resolved the problem).